# Build file to another project in same solution

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In my VS 2k15 solution I have 5 projects. One of them handles everything regarding logging and has an xml configuration file which needs to build to my main web project.

How can I fix this so it automatically sends the config file on each build to the main project?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to right-click your project. Enter the Build tab. Here you will find an output section.

Here is an output path where you can fill in (or browse) the active bin directory (the one of your main project).

Hope this helps you? I struggled with this same problem a while ago.